# Applying motion to a 3d Cube - GLKit

Tags: ios, glkit

I am coding a 3d cube that can be rotated on touch using GLKit. How can a 3d Cube be manipulated to rotate in using the touch direction and velocity?

I would like to apply the direction and velocity to the cube so that it continues to spin after being swiped.

How exactly does one do this using transformation?

I currently convert the matrix in the `GLKitViewController delegate` update method and apply it

```
GLKMatrix4 viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);   
GLKMatrix4 rotation = GLKMatrix4MakeWithQuaternion(_quat);
viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(viewMatrix, rotation);
self.effect.transform.viewMatrix = viewMatrix;
```

How can I apply this transform to the cube after touches have ended?

Comment: For rotations like this, you should learn about quaternions. For turning a 2D swipe into a 3D rotation, you will need to decide how you want it to behave; there are several options, the most popular place an imaginary ball of some radius in the scene and keep the "mouse" locked to a particular point on its surface, but that causes non-intuitive behaviour when moving outside the ball.

Comment: I would like to somehow capture the touch and apply it to the cube after touch ends. I can currently rotate it on touch, but am not sure how to apply the velocity of the touch gesture to the rotation.

Comment: In that case you'll need to explain what the current end result is. Do you have a rotation matrix? If so, you can simply continue applying it, but as I say, better is to create a quaternion from the matrix so that it is more numerically stable and can be applied smoothly (i.e. you can change the angle of rotation without changing the direction)

Comment: I do convert the matrix to a qauternion. please check updated question.

Comment: I don't understand; if you already have a rotation which you can apply, then it's simply a matter of continuously applying that rotation, possibly with some damping. Or store the previous state and apply the rotation with an ever-increasing theta see `GLKQuaternionSlerp` for the latter (`t` can be > 1).

Comment: I am new to OpenGL so Im sorry if the questions are noob. I captured the needed locations and rotation differences during touch movements on the cube and I apply then when touches end, the problem is it does nothing to the cube.

Comment: are you marking the view to be redrawn as you animate it? Also it sounds like you would be better off starting a new question, because it seems your problem isn't really related to the rotation at all (I'm not sure what it is related to though)

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will create a new question.